# Text carousel crossfade effect?

Tags: jquery, fade

We're trying to implement a simple text carousel that replaces a single word in a sentence with a few other words. They will fade in/out and the containers width should shrink/enlarge to accomodate the new word. Sounds simple enough but we're having a hard time.

Should function like the second line on [www.branch.com](http://www.branch.com).

Can't find a plugin for this? Image carousel sure, but not text, and not one that changes the preceding container.

It goes through the words but the container needs to change widths.

```
    $('#caption p:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#caption span:first-child').fadeOut('slow')
           .next('span').fadeIn('slow')
           .end().appendTo('#caption');
    }, 2000);
```

This is the

```
 <div id="caption">
      <span>best</span>
      <span>ultimate</span>
      <span>excellent</span>
      <span>fantastic</span>
   </div>
```

website in town.

```
#container {
   position: relative;
}

#container p {
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: we added the transition code, but we're lost with the width change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to achieve a more `branch.com`-like effect, you'll need the following additions/changes":

**Regarding CSS**:

`#caption` needs:

- padding: 0px;
- display: inline-block;
- position: relative;
- vertical-align: bottom;
- transition: width 0.25s linear;

`#caption > span` needs:

- position: absolute;
- top: 0px;
- left: 0px;

**Regarding JS**:
You'll need to explicitely set `#caption`'s width to the width of the shown element (each time a transition happens), using soimething like this:

```
$("#caption").css("width", $(<the_element_to_be_shown>).width());
```

You'll also have to set the initial width and height:

```
$("#caption").css("width", $("#caption > span:first-child").width());
$("#caption").css("height", $("#caption > span:first-child").height());
```

I put it all together in this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/YnG9t/)**.

Comment: Always glad to help :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 3):

i hope this will do the trick http://jsfiddle.net/JVuEv/

```
function ticker() {
    var caption = $('#caption');
    var elements = caption.children();
    $(elements[0]).fadeOut('slow', function () {
        caption.append($(this));
        $(elements[1]).show();
    });
}
```