# Crossfading jQuery breaks when I replace <font> tags with more <span>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fade

I have a funky jQuery cross-fading text carousel from borrowed code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16642779/text-carousel-crossfade-effect/16644034)/[here](https://gist.github.com/shashisp/8703545)), and I'm providing formatted text via Included html generated dynamically by external php. It's exactly the effect I needed.

The thing is, it works fine... but **only** if I use a ton of `<FONT COLOR>` tags to get the desired formatting (**several colors per word**). I've read repeatedly that it's imperative that I don't use `<FONT>` since it's deprecated and therefore will makes babies cry or something.

---

### Working MCVE:

```js
$("#caption").css("width", $("#caption > span:first-child").width());
$("#caption").css("height", $("#caption > span:first-child").height());
var captionIdx = 0;
var captionItemCount = $("#caption > span").length;
setInterval(function() {
  $("#caption span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")").fadeOut("slow");
  captionIdx = (captionIdx + 1) % captionItemCount;
  var $next = $("#caption span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")");
  $("#caption").css("width", $next.width());
  $("#caption").css("height", $next.height());
  $next.fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000);
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#caption {
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  transition: width 0.25s linear;
}

#caption>span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#caption>span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    This task is
    <span id="caption">
<span><a href="http://lnk1.co"><font color=red>Confu</font><font color=green>sing</font></a></span>
    <span><a href="http://lnk2.co"><font color=green>Frust</font><font color=blue>rating</font></a></span>
    <span><a href="http://lnk3.co"><font color=blue>Tire</font><font color=red>some</font></a></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

...so I'm trying to switch to using CSS instead, **but it 'breaks' the carousel**, presumably since I need additional `<SPAN>`s to apply the formatting, while the jQuery uses `<SPAN>`'s as the delimiter in phrase rotation.

---

### Broken MCVE:

**Note** the only difference is 3 lines of `<style>` and the 3 lines within `<span id="caption">`.

```js
$("#caption").css("width", $("#caption > span:first-child").width());
$("#caption").css("height", $("#caption > span:first-child").height());
var captionIdx = 0;
var captionItemCount = $("#caption > span").length;
setInterval(function() {
  $("#caption span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")").fadeOut("slow");
  captionIdx = (captionIdx + 1) % captionItemCount;
  var $next = $("#caption span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")");
  $("#caption").css("width", $next.width());
  $("#caption").css("height", $next.height());
  $next.fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.w1 { color: #FF0000; }
.w2 { color: #00FF00; }
.w3 { color: #0000FF; }

#container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#caption {
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  transition: width 0.25s linear;
}

#caption>span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#caption>span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    This task is
    <span id="caption">

<span><a href="http://lnk1.co"><span class="w1">Very</span><span class="w2">Frustrating</span></a></span>
<span><a href="http://lnk2.co"><span class="w2">Just</span><span class="w3">Alright</span></a></span>
<span><a href="http://lnk3.co"><span class="w3">Totally</span><span class="w1">Perfect</span></a></span>

    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've been experimenting with various combinations of [`div`s & `span`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400823/why-doesnt-my-div-inside-a-span-work-properly/21400869), and `Display` properties like `inline-block` but since I'm not clear on what the jQuery is *doing*, I can't get it working while still on a single line.

***Is there a quick fix?***

---

**Bonus Question:**
Is it really a big deal to use deprecated tags like `<FONT>` or  `<B>`?  I can't imagine that any browser is going to allow them to just "stop working" with an update anytime soon; rendering millions of old pages non-functional (while their competition still supports the deprecated tags)...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#caption").css("width", $("#caption > span:first-child").width());
$("#caption").css("height", $("#caption > span:first-child").height());
var captionIdx = 0;
var captionItemCount = $("#caption > span").length;
setInterval(function() {
  $("#caption > span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")").fadeOut("slow");
  captionIdx = (captionIdx + 1) % captionItemCount;
  var $next = $("#caption > span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")");
  $("#caption").css("width", $next.width());
  $("#caption").css("height", $next.height());
  $next.fadeIn("slow");
}, 2000);
```

```css
.w1 { color: #FF0000; }
.w2 { color: #00FF00; }
.w3 { color: #0000FF; }

#container {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

#caption {
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -ms-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: width 0.25s linear;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#caption>span {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

#caption>span:first-child {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    This task is
    <span id="caption">

<span><a href="http://lnk1.co"><span class="w1">Very</span><span class="w2">Frustrating</span></a></span>
<span><a href="http://lnk2.co"><span class="w2">Just</span><span class="w3">Alright</span></a></span>
<span><a href="http://lnk3.co"><span class="w3">Totally</span><span class="w1">Perfect</span></a></span>

    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

You need to use `>` to select only the immidiate child `span` and not all descendant `span`s  in `$("#caption > span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")").fadeOut("slow");` and `var $next = $("#caption > span:eq(" + captionIdx + ")");`. Since you did not use `>` all inner `span`s are animated too, that's why you see this strange effect.

Comment: When I predicted that it's probably a "quick fix", I didn't expect that fix to be literally **one** character...  *Awesome, thanks!*  (also, frustrating to think of how long I wasted because of one character!)